# WooCommerce: How can I add an internal link button when products have no price?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, hook-woocommerce

In case products have **no price** I would like to have a **custom button** on the single product page.

Simply noted I need a code that:

1. Checks if the price is 0 or empty
2. If so creates a button on the product page

That's it.

I spent a lot of time figuring out a conditional that can check the price of a product and then reacts to it, but I couldn't find a clear answer. I would hugely appreciate it if you guys could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
global $post, $product;

if($product->get_price() ==0){

     $shop_page_url = get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );
     echo "<a href='$shop_page_url'>Shop</a>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Dev Danidhariya, though this gives an error:

"The code snippet you are trying to save produced a fatal error on line 3:

Call to a member function get_price() on a non-object"

(I am using the plug-in code snippets)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Though I would prefer it to be in the snippets. To me it seems more organised and update-proof. Is this possible?